# Vision Transformer for Visual Odometry Regression gives the same output for all inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I'm using a Spatio Temporal Vision Transformer known as ViViT, which traditionally is used for video classification, as my model for predicting the change of pose. Pose is the position and orientation of an agent, in this case a camera.

In the training stpe, the model is capable of predicting diverse values and even gives accurate estimates for the path of an agent. In the image below, we see in blue the Ground Truth, and in orange the predicted path:

[Odometry plot, ground truth vs predicted in training step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmGhK.png)

However, in the testing fase, the model doesn't show any capabilities of predicting the change of pose.

[Odometry plot, ground truth vs predicted in testing step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8YPg.png)

What I feed my model is two images stacked on top of each other. One image corresponds to the instant t and the next one to the instant t+1. I am using the KITTI odometry set.

```
The shape of my input tensor is the following - [B, C, F, H, W], where:
B = Batches (The size of the batch)
C = Channels (RGB, GrayScale, etc)
F = Number of frames stacked on top of each other (In my particular case this dimension is where I do torch.cat of my images)
H, W = Height, Width
```

I wasn't expecting great results but I also wasn't expecting the same output for every single input. If i feed my network a random tensor, like

```
torch.rand(1, 3, 2, 370, 1241)
```

I get the same output for every diferent tensor.

Also, I have a custom loss function set up:

[Custom loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVyAu.png)

I am using RMSProp as my optimizer.

```
For better understanding of the model I am using I have here a pastebin: [Pastebin for the model](https://pastebin.com/3sHjpxng)
```

I am stuck with this for the last 3 weeks. Any help would be appreciated.